How to avoid persisting bpy properties to .blend files
I have a few operators that are effectively batch scripts that perform bulk operations on objects in a scene or .blend file.  Each operator is a one-shot thing that has no need for the followup tweaking that normally seems to accompany operators with properties.
My current setup is a panel in the 'PROPERTIES' area that uses a property group attached to the scene to store settings for operator execution.  This works fine, but it bothers me that those properties become persisted as junk data in the .blend file when they have no purpose once an operator execution has finished.
What I want is to have those options be ephemeral and exist only for the lifetime of a session, but it is unclear to me how I would accomplish that.
Looking to the built-in panels, it seems that my goal may not be possible?  For example, the Object Properties > Data > Remesh panel has the same basic setup I do, but implements those options as properties on the Mesh object which are persisted in the .blend file.
I have considered using a popup property dialog window for the options, but that would mean duplicating options that apply to more than one operator (and requiring those options be set for each operator individually) in addition to hiding the available options and information behind a button click which wouldn't be a great UX.

Hello. I believe if you attach your properties to bpy.types.WindowManager the properties are cleared when you quit Blender. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html However it might also be cleaned when you save / load a file and when you undo / redo so exercise caution. Access with bpy.context.window_manager

@Gorgious, thank you!  It does appear that props attached to the window manager are not persisted to the .blend file.  If you want to make an answer with your comment, I can mark it as the accepted answer to the question

If you attach your properties to bpy.types.WindowManager the properties are cleared when you quit Blender. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html
However it might also be cleared when you save / load a file and when you undo / redo so exercise caution. Access with bpy.types.WindowManager and bpy.context.window_manager.
